# how to use Wireshark between k8s pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, wireshark

I want to use Wireshark to sniff packets between two k8s pods. I want to run Wireshark on my host laptop where k8s is installed. Basically, I need to run Wireshark from the node and capture inter pod communication. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Wireshark** is a graphical network packet analyzing tool based on pcap(API for network packet capture). Using this tool, you can easily perform analysis by protocol filtering, port, and many other packet attributes.

Below are the steps to install and capture the pod packets in kubernetes

1. You must install the [Wireshark application](https://computingforgeeks.com/capture-kubernetes-pods-packets-using-tcpdump/#:%7E:text=Install%20Wireshark%20Application) on your local system.
2. Need to configure the Wireshark to be able to capture the packets as a normal user. First add the user to the Wireshark group by running this command:

   sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
3. Set the right permission for dumpcap binary file.

   sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/dumpcap sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/dumpcap
4. Verify the changes made

   $ sudo getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap /usr/bin/dumpcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip
5. To capture the kubernetes pods packets using tcpdump and Wireshark, use the below syntax:

   kubectl plugin sniff <POD_NAME> [-n <NAMESPACE_NAME>] [-c <CONTAINER_NAME>] --image <PRIVATE_REPO>/docker --tcpdump-image <PRIVATE_REPO>/tcpdump
6. Wireshark will monitor entire traffic coming to a particular pod, based on the IP address  of source and destination we can filter the traffic between two pods.

For more information refer to the blog written by [Klinsmann Oteyo](https://computingforgeeks.com/capture-kubernetes-pods-packets-using-tcpdump/) on how to capture Kubernetes pods packets using Wireshark.